# Вывести категории из поля mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица вида:

```
id  title       cat
1   название_1  категория_1
2   название_2  категория_2
3   название_3  категория_2
4   название_4  категория_4
5   название_5  категория_1
```

Как одним запросом можно вывести весь список категорий из поля cat, чтобы они не повторялись и выглядели так:

```
Категория_1
Категория_2
Категория_4
```

Comment: select distinct?

Comment: Группировка + сортировка по взростанию. `SELECT cat FROM table GROUP BY cat ORDER BY cat ASC`